# Show that $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{x}{1+x})^n$ uniformly converge on each closed interval of $(\frac{-1}{2},\infty)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{x}{1+x})^n$ uniformly converge on each closed interval of $(\frac{-1}{2},\infty)$.

I know that that is a geometric sum which converge to $x$. but i failed to show the it uniformly converges. i got stuck in this step:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup(\sum_{n=1}^N (\frac{x}{1+x})^N-x)=...=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup(x(\frac{x}{1+x})^N)=?$$

I  also tried to show uniformly coverage with the Weierstrass M-test without any success.

I think that in both options my problem is to value the supremum or the maximum in close interval.

**one more related question:** why does proving the above will ensure that $F(x)$ is continuous on $(\frac{-1}{2},\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^{n-1}-(1+x)^n$ (with $n>1$) is decreasing with maximum in $x=-\dfrac1n>-\dfrac12$ so $f(x)\leq\left(\dfrac12\right)^n$ then
$$\Big|\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^n-x\Big|=\Big|\dfrac{xf(x)}{(1+x)^n}\Big|\leq\Big|\dfrac{x}{1+nx}\Big|\left(\dfrac12\right)^n\leq\dfrac{1}{n2^n}\to0$$

Comment: Is it not showing the opposite? that  
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup(\sum_{n=1}^N (\frac{x}{1+x})^N-x)\to x\neq0$$ ?

Comment: @Y.ofir I wrote the whole solution with your definition.